# How can I build a custom Page in my Filament App Panel which checks the route for a token before giving access to a form?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I am using Filament 3 with Laravel 10 and I want a custom Page, accessible without login for User Invitations. The Invitation works via an internally generated token. This Token is also a Model. Before allowing to create a new User with a form, I want to check if the route (the entered link in the browser) contains a token which is in my database. How can this be achieved as vanilla/codeless as possible / with Filament "Thinking"?

I cannot see a possibility to change my route and put in a parameter for the token which I could evaluate somewhere else. Only solution I see is using a custom livewire component with custom route and putting my filament form into this.

Comment: why not create a route with parameter? then use that param to query to your model.

Comment: this is what I suggested already in my last sentence. i wanted to know if its possible to directly create a custom filament page and edit the route for that so it includes a token string instead of creating custom livewire and include filament form!